# Left right scroll on UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I'm trying to implement a scrollView on my `UINavigationBar` like the Tinder UI.

When I implement it using

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:self.navigationBarScrollView];
```

the scrollView, shifts below like so:

[image]

Now when I use

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = self.navigationBarScrollView;
```

I get this:

[image]

Is there another approach to it?

PS - the iPhone screenshot is an image in a `UITableView`.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6838917/objective-c-how-to-make-navigation-bar-scroll-with-tableview

Comment: @DarshanKunjadiya not up and down. Need it to be left and right.

Answer (score 1):

Create your navigationBar for yours controllers.
You can add to it all, what you want.